# Perfect union join to get results

Tags: sql-server

I union join two columns where i get  records of c@mail.com avaiable in two in columns. which that works perfectly. But what i want to achieve is when a particular user "bb@mail.com" is logged on, on click on user c@mail.com, he should be able to see the messages sent to him by c@mail.com, also when c@mail.com should logged in he too must be able to see message sent to him by b@mail.com
because when i execute i seem to get all the messages c@mail.com has sent to every users in the table.
 how do i join these fields to make it work

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   dbo.IM
        INNER JOIN profile ON im.sid = profile.profile_id
 WHERE  sid = '3'
        AND im_sender = 'c@mail.com'
 UNION
 SELECT *
 FROM   dbo.IM
        INNER JOIN profile ON im.sid = profile.profile_id
 WHERE  rid = '2'
        AND im_reciever = 'bb@mail.com'
 ORDER BY id ASC
```

i'm using an image below to explain.  i want to only return records sent by the logged in user  c@mail.com to cgblay....., but as you see records of also e@mail.com is also found
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset. I'm afraid your explanation is difficult to follow.

Comment: So you want a where clause? I am not exactly sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your problem. Seems you are after this

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.IM
        INNER JOIN profile ON im.sid = profile.profile_id
WHERE  sid = '3'
       AND im_sender = 'c@mail.com'
       and rid = '2'
       AND im_reciever = 'bb@mail.com'
```